# How to MOVE VALUE OF A NEW RECORD ADDED from subfile to physical file in RPGLE?

Tags: move, rpgle

How to move value of a new record added from SUBFILE into physical file?

The value are as shown in picture below:

[image: CREATE]

CUREXG are name of my physical file(pf), CURREC is my record name. My pf look like this :

[image: PF]

How to make the value separated into the pyhsical file?
What should I do? Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Some may be a little confused, but there is no subfile involved here. Maybe you meant display file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brute force method suggested by RockBoro will work, though with a lot of duplicate code. One way to reduce the duplicate code (DRY principle) is to redefine the display file record structure using an array. Though you didn't give us the DDS for the display file record, I am guessing the record format looks something like this:

```
dcl-f DSPF    Workstn Qualified;
dcl-ds rec    LikeRec(DSPF.screen: *all) Inz;
```

Where the 5 rates fall one after another. You can overlay an array on that like this:

```
dcl-s rates   Like(rec.usd3) dim(5) based(pRates);
dcl-s pRates  Pointer Inz(%addr(rec.usd3));
```

After reading the screen just loop through the rates and write to the physical file:

```
exfmt DSPF.screen rec;
for ix = 1 to %elem(rates);
  exgdat = rec.date;
  exgcod = exccd(ix);
  exgrat = rates(ix);
  write currec;
endfor;
```

You would also need a compile time array `exccd` to hold the exchange codes in the order that they appear in the display file to make this work.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to write all value at the same time?

Comment: Only with SQL. You would build an array of records and insert multiple rows from the array. What would you be trying to accomplish with this? If you are using record level access, the database takes care of blocking where it is more efficient.

Comment: Can i do without using sql?

Comment: I think I got it. I referred to your code and it works. Thank you sir!

Comment: Using RPG `CHAIN` and `WRITE` op codes is called record level access (RLA) for a reason. each operation works on a single record. So no you can't write multiple records at once with RLA op codes. You can only do that with SQL.

Comment: I got it when I use compile time array. And after that I use for loop to get the next value, and it works

Answer (score 1):

each currency record stores the currency rate of a single currency code and date. So you have to write multiple records. One for each currency code.

```
 \free
      exgdat = date ;
      exgcur = 'USD' ;
      exgamt = usd ;
      write  currec ;
 \end-free
```

Try to use SQL.  It is built into the system.  And makes for more readable code.

```
   exec sql
   insert into  exgrat  ( exgdat, exgcur, exgamt )
   values( :date, 'USD', :usd ) ;
```